# Visual Studio request build before Check In

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I would like to make visual studio requests for build before check in to TFS. Is that possible?

Arleady I have implemented Build Definiton and made a Check-In Policy, but it's building on TFS Build server.

I just want to have logic "Build, then check-in. If build fails, do not check in"

Is that possible to do that?

Comment: Verifying a build on a build server is much better than verifying a local build. Even if the local build succeeds, you might be missing files to check in or you might reference some files only installed on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Morten,

Starting on VS.Net 2010 the Gated check-in feature do exactaly what you want! You will found this feature on Trigger menu on build definition screen.
When you queue a build what will fail, your code is not checked-in on source control.

Comment: This is what I mentioned. I would like to make a gate on my computer side, not on a TFS build server.

Comment: Why?  As Morten said in his comment on your question doing it on the server is the recommended way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Gated check-in works only with TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control), a centralized source code repository. There is no meaning to work locally!